# Android UsbManager.openDevice(Device device) throw an Exception "device does not exist or be restricted"

Tags: android, usb

I use a thread to send data to my usb-device (not data-storage) and get the return-data from device.

It worked fine in the first 5 minute. Data in, data out. (I almost start to sing in the sixth minute.)

Then suddenly it lost the connection.

There are the logcat message:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: device /dev/bus/usb/001/002 does not exist or is restricted
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1331)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
    at android.hardware.usb.IUsbManager$Stub$Proxy.openDevice(IUsbManager.java:340)
    at android.hardware.usb.UsbManager.openDevice(UsbManager.java:255)
```

So, I check the code of `UsbManager`, trying to find out what is the `IUsbManager`...

Cool. An interface... and there is zero information about what it is.  That is why I am here.

Has anyone with any clue???

Comment: Hello, I get this same exception when i restart my usb-device. I suspect your permission to use the device is "re-requested". When this happens to me I have to re-connect the usb cable. I haven't found any fixes to this yet though.

Comment: Have u got the solution? I m getting same exception while trying to connect usb CDC class.

Comment: You need to release your UsbConnection.
I can't give a exacly number. It's about ten times data-sending then one time releasing. (And get a UsbConnection again....)

Comment: @ErikSoderstrom what do you mean with "re-requested"? Btw, experiencing the same problem... Did you find a solution...?

Comment: Sorry. Not re-request. I should say ... re-open ( UsbManager.openDeivice)\

Answer (score 2):

The app should be listening to the `UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` and `UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED` Intents. It should attempt to open the device received from the `attached` intent.

The error usually happens when the app tries to re-open the connection to a UsbDevice. When the UsbDevice reconnects it is assigned a new hardware address (Old: `/dev/bus/usb/001/002`, New: `/dev/bus/usb/001/003`).

Comment: ＯＭＧ  So the connection to DEVICE can be disconnect. Then we  need to wait for the listener get new DEVICE and continue the task.